# DataGridView BackColor

Tags: c#

I want that the active records of my dataGridView have some backcolor.
So I use RowEnter, RowLeave methods in my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor =
  Color.FromArgb(231, 255, 231);          
}

private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;
}
```

All works, but very, very slow. Is there a more effective way to achieve this effect in WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use javascript to make this efficient

Try this below code

```
protected void MyGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {

    string rowStyle = "this.style.backgroundColor
    = 'yellow'";
    string rowStyleClickedTwice =
    "this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'";
    string rowID = String.Empty; 

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        rowID = "row"+e.Row.RowIndex; 

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("id",
        "row"+e.Row.RowIndex);
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick",
        "ChangeRowColor(" +"'" + rowID + "'" + ")");
    }       
}
```

and you can configure your javascript below :

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenColor"  />
 <script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 


 function ChangeRowColor(rowID) 
 { 
     var color = document.getElementById(rowID).style.backgroundColor;
     alert(color);   

     if(color != 'yellow') 
     document.getElementById("hiddenColor").style.backgroundColor = color;

     alert(oldColor); 

     if(color == 'yellow')
    document.getElementById(rowID).style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("hiddenColor").style.backgroundColor;
     else
     document.getElementById(rowID).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';             

  }
</script>
```

Just let me know when it works

Comment: I forgot to say that it’s in WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this :

```
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        private int mMousedOverColumnIndex = int.MinValue;
        private int mMousedOverRowIndex = int.MinValue;

        protected override void OnCellMouseEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            mMousedOverColumnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
            mMousedOverRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
            base.OnCellMouseEnter(e);
            base.Refresh();
        }

        protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((e.ColumnIndex == mMousedOverColumnIndex) && (e.RowIndex == -1)) ||
                ((e.ColumnIndex == -1) && (e.RowIndex == mMousedOverRowIndex)))
            {
                PaintColumnHeader(e, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            }
            base.OnCellPainting(e);
        }

        private void PaintColumnHeader(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e, System.Drawing.Color color)
        {
            LinearGradientBrush backBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100), color, color);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, e.CellBounds);
            DataGridViewPaintParts parts = (DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Background);
            e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, parts);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you feel this works

Comment: Thank you, @Javalovers, I’ll try this, but I am afraid it’s not exactly what I want. Mouse has nothing to do with my task. I just want that the active row has additional background color.

Comment: Dear @Peter you can change the event pal referring to your requirement

Comment: I’ve checked your code, it’s works all right, but again, no gaining in speed, if mouse is inside dataGrid, there is visible redrawing of all fonts in dataGrid and everything is hardly moving. Once the mouse is outside the grid, all just flies. I think I should find some other walk around. Thank you, @javalovers, just the same. There are many new things for me in your example, for instance – how to change color of the header on mouse enter. Maybe you would be so kind as to give me an example how to prebuilt grid in my custom dataGridView. Here is how I tried to accomplish this but no success:

Comment: `public class DGV : DataGridView
    {
                  
        private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column1;

        public DGV()
        {
            InitializeClass();
        }

            void InitializeClass()
            {
                this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                this.column1.DataPropertyName = "Location";
                this.column1.HeaderText = "Location";
                this.column1.Name = "column1";

              
            }


        }`

Comment: For the life of me, I can’t understand how to format my comment correctly…

Comment: For a single test you might get the result but to get a better comparison result you may check the load test system that can be useful to compare the result

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.State & DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) != 0)
        e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
}
```